# Adding filenames to combobox except filenames containing certain text

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using this code to add filenames to a dropdown:

```
    Dim AddToFilter As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path)
    For Each NameThing As FileInfo In AddToFilter.GetFiles("*.xlsx", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        Dim FileName As String = NameThing.Name
        FileName = FileName.Replace(".xlsx", "")
        cmbStateFilter.Items.Add(FileName)
    Next
```

This code works for adding the file names excluding the extension, but if I have 4 files:
1. "Test1"
2. "Test2"
3. "ABCDTest3"
4. "902Test4"
How do I prevent the files that start with ABCD and 902 from being added to this dropdown?

Comment: `String` have a  [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Oh! It worked! I'd like to mark something as an answer, so would it be possible for you to write something short and sweet so that I may mark it?

Comment: You can answer your own questions